# XCUITest - What else can I use besides sleep to find an item on the screen after the back button was clicked?

Tags: xcuitest

We have multiple iOS XCUITests for which a back button was clicked.  After this click, we do something else in the test ( many various things depending on the test ).  However, on certain screens in our app, no matter what step is next ( another button click, an assertion, etc. ), the test will fail unless a sleep is used.  It seems like the test is not waiting for the next screen to finish what it is doing.  This could be drawing ui elements, background items running, etc.  When I add a sleep of 5 seconds, the tests are fine and continue to completion with no issues.  In automation, it's my understanding that sleeps are not ideal and should be avoided if possible.  Also, I believe the XCUITests have some built in wait time to wait for elements.  However, in this case, without the sleep, the test fails then.

So, to improve out automation tests, what are some suggestions we can try besides sleep for screen transitions like this back button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wait for an element on new screen to appear or wait for an element on the previous screen to disappear.

Use `newElement.waitForExistence(timeout: 5)`

or

`previousElement.waitForDisappearance(timeout: 5)`

Grab `waitForDisappearance` here https://github.com/devexperts/screenobject

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I added in some waits for items that would load a little further down the screen.  This seems to be working so far.  Waiting just on the element we were to tap on, with the default waits built into XCode, was not working.  I just wonder how XCode finds the element but it's not usable.  It seems like it should figure it out better than it does.  Regardless, using this method of waiting for something else that should load after the element I want is a good idea and seems to be working.  Thanks!

Comment: I find `waitForExistence` to be far more useful given pages are usually slow to load as opposed to slow to go away.